# wifi provider onLocationChanged is never called

Tags: android, location, android-wifi

I got a weird problem. I uses wifi to retrieve user location. I have tested on several phones; on some of them, I could never get a location update. it seemed that the method onLocationChanged is never called. My code is attached below.. Any suggestions appreciated!!!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  LocationManager locationManager;
  locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  String provider = locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
  Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

  updateWithNewLocation(l);

  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0,
                                       locationListener);
}

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
  TextView myLocationText;
  myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);

  String latLongString = "No location found";
  if (location != null) {
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
  }

  myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" +
                       latLongString);
}

private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    updateWithNewLocation(location);
    Log.i("onLocationChanged", "onLocationChanged");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location changed", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                            Bundle extras) {}
```

};

Manifest

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Which device you are testing on?

Comment: Try using new LocationListener() inside the requestLocationUpdate(). Also check if you can receive the network gps data in the settings of your device.

Comment: Make sure you are allowing the device to use location, as sharing or using location requires the user agreement.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the phones on which you don't get location updates from do not have proper data connection. Network Provider needs GSM/3G or WiFi data connection to retrieve a location fix from Google servers using phones's cell/wifi data. You can use the method below to check this.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
ConnectivityManager cm =
    (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your onProviderDisabled method is not being called immediately.

If you find it is being called as soon as your provider registers, it means that the phone you're on has location services disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It's my suspicion now that Google Location Services were down in select areas. My app started working again with no changes to the code (the apk from the Play Store).

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue with `NetworkProvider` while testing in `ICS`(4.0) but working fine in older versions(2.2 and 2.3.3 i tested). Here is the solution i found and working fine in `ICS` as well. Please use the `Criteria` for getting the location updates as below:

```
 LocationManager locationManager= (LocationManager) <YourAct>
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);  //ACCURACY_COARSE or ACCURACY_FINE based on usage

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location
    // updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Replace the code as above. This will help u in getting the location updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem and in turns out that `onLocationChanged` is not called if there is `getLastKnownLocation` which is the same as "current". That means that you will not get new location because there is nothing new to report...
Solution is to use the last known location even it is very old (and continue to listen for updates if you need more precise/new location (if such occurres)).