# onLocationChanged doesn't invoked when the wifi is turn off in settings but cell network is available

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have upgraded my locations app to use the google maps v2. 
everything works well but I see one strange behavior of the v2 fused provider:
**when I turn off the WIFI in the settings, although the cell network is available, the `onLocationChanged` callback doesn't invoked!**
 if the wifi is turn on in settings, (and no WIFI network is available but only the cell network) the `onLocationChanged` callback is invoked well.
in the old version of the app that uses v1 this behavior doesn't happen.

do anyone know why this happens and how to solve it??

thank you for giving your time.

**edit:** the code i'm using for getting locations updates (the main parts):

```
            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(context, this, this);
        // Start with updates turned off
        mUpdatesRequested = false;
        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationClient.connect();
```

then:

```
  @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                LocationV2.this);
    }
```

Comment: You might be checking only the wi-fi location. Paste the code where you do the update of the location. There are separate parameters for wi-fi and roaming data, so you might be just using the first one.

Comment: in V2 you aren't specify the provider to use but only requestLocationUpdates and the best location is taken automatically. isn't it?

Comment: Well, I don't know the exact implementation, you should tell me that. Paste the code that you use. You have 4 ways of invoking `requestLocationUpdates` (see here ->  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long, float, android.location.Criteria, android.app.PendingIntent)). You'll need to provide the provider, criteria etc. you can even use PASSIVE_PROVIDER, lastknown location etc. Here's one more example `locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, locationListener, null);`. Tell me how do you get this.

Comment: Take a look here - > http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html . As said there - Use with a priority constant such as `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`. No other values are accepted.

The priority of the request is a strong hint to the LocationClient for which location sources to use. For example, PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY is more likely to use GPS, and PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY is more likely to use WIFI & Cell tower positioning, but it also depends on many other factors (such as which sources are available) and is implementation dependent.

Comment: In brief, try changing the flag `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` (which uses the GPs most likely, to `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` this wil turn to the wi-fi or the network's 3G .

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work :(

Comment: what permissions did you grant in the manifest to access the location?

Comment: Based on the method you use, I can only suggest this flag change. however, if you are willing to try something else, I can give you the class I'm using for the location updates, but it doesn't use `LocationClient` - instead it's using `LocationManager`.

Comment: it can't be problem of permissions because the locations are updated from all providers correctly. the problem is that when the wifi is off the onLocationChanged isn't invoked

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, and after a couple of hours spent looking for an explanation, it seems that onLocationChanged isn't fired because the current location is the same as the previous one. Indeed, with cell network, the accuracy is worse.
I suggest you to use [LocationManager#getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)

[Here is a more detailed commen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14012799/2105309)t

Please let me know if you've found another solution.

Comment: but why it happens only when wifi is turn off in setting?? when it turn on, although no wifi is available the onLocationChanged is invoked!! do you have this problem??

Comment: because even when wifi is on but you're not connected to a network, location can work thanks to your 3G. The location will be based on the nearest wifi access point